# Compiling and deploying RTOS to an MCU

Tags: c, operating-systems, cpu, real-time, arm

**Please note:** Even though I'm specifically talking about an RTOS called [Embox](https://github.com/embox/embox) here, and even though I'm talking about AVR/ARm, I think this question can be answered by anybody whose ever done a fair amount of C-based MCU programming.

I'm interested in building Embox locally on my machine and seeing if I can flash/deploy it to an AVR/ARM-based MCU. Unfortunately I'm on Windows 7, and so I had to install MinGW to get access to things like GCC (`g++`, `make`, etc.) I have written a simple "Hello World" C program and got it building successfully into a `helloworld.exe` executable.

I cloned Embox and followed their instructions for buildig their ARM-STM32_V1 template, but ran into a slew of errors that I'm still wading through. Don't worry, that's not my question here. What I *am* wondering, since I'm currently blocked, is much more basic and fundamental to the understanding of RTOSes and MCU programming:

- What is the deployable unit(s) of Embox? That is, when its all said and done, what file(s) will I be flashing on to the MCU, effectively *deploying* the RTOS to it?
- How do you deploy these files to an MCU? Can I assume SPI, UART, USART, JTAG, etc. are the usual suspects? How can I tell what approach is compatible with Embox and/or the MCU?
- How do you configure the MCU to start Embox when the chip powers on? Or does that happen for you as a result of flashing the files to the MCU?

If someone could help answer these, I think I'll have a much better understanding of the "big picture" behind MCU-based programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the deployable unit(s) of Embox?

As most of RTOS for MCU Embox offers deployable unit as a single image. For Embox It has ELF format and is placed in "./build/base/bin/embox" file.

> How do you deploy these files to an MCU?

It depends on MCU not RTOS. The most popular hardware interface for loading images is JTAG. Here is an [example](https://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/PlatformStm32Discovery) how load image on STM32Discovery

> How do you configure the MCU to start Embox when the chip powers on?

Starting procedure is also CPU dependently, but in common it can be presented as follow: When the chip powers on PC (program counter) is setup to 'start adress' and CPU begin executing the command.